# Pushing my Mercurial Repository through HTTP with Apache and Windows

Tags: ssl, mercurial, apache2, windows-server-2003

So I have managed it. I can clone mercurial-repositories remotely using HTTP to my Windows Server 2003 machine and the ipaddress from that machine. Although I did deactivate IIS6 and am using Apache 2.2.x now. But not all works right now...darn! Here's the thing:

Cloning goes smooth! But when I want to push my changes to the original repository I get the message "cannot lock static http-repository". On the internet I get to read several explanations that Mercurial wasn't designed to push over HTTP connections. Still, on the Mercurial website there's something about configuring an **hgrc file**.

There's also the possibilty to configure Apache to host via HTTPS (or SSL). For this you have to load the module enabling OpenSSL and generating keys.

**Configuring the hgrc file**
Just add "push_ssl = false" under the [web] line. But where to put this file when pushing your changes back?! Because I placed it in the root of the server, in the ".hg" directory, nothing works.

**Using SSL/HTTPS with Apache**
When I try to access 'https://myipaddress' it fails, displaying a dutch message which would mean something like "server taking too long to respond". Trying to push also gives me a dutch error message which means about the same. It can not connect to my server via https although I followed the steps exactly at [this blog](http://troymurray.blogspot.com/2007/09/apache-22-with-ssl-on-windows-server.html).

I don't care which of the above solutions will work for me. Turns out none of them work so far. So please, can anyone help me with one of the solutions above? Pick the easiest! Help will be greatly appreciated, not only from me.

**Summary**
-Windows Server 2003
-Apache 2.2 with OpenSSL
-Mercurial 1.8.2
-I can clone, but not push!

Thank you!

Maarten Baar(s)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you might have apache configured incorrectly for getting it to do what you want. Based on your question it sounds like you have a path (maybe the root of the server) pointing to the repository you want to serve.

Mercurial comes with a script for this exact purpose, in the latest version it is hgweb.cgi. There are reasonably good instructions for setting it up [on the mercurial site](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep). It should allow both cloning and pushing. You will need the `push_ssl=false` if you will not be configuring https and also an `allow_push` line which will let certain users, or all (*) push to the repository. But all that should be part of the setup docs.

Comment: I got SSL working. Many people say it's unwise to transfer sensitive data through http only. But still I get the message "cannot lock static-http repository". I use hgweb.cgi and have set http://mydomain/hg as ScriptAlias to the hgweb.cgi. In the hgweb.cgi i have a collection of repositories to http://mydomain/repositories/. There are my repo's. But how can I push to a specific repository without bumping into the error "cannot lock static-http repository"?